# rails complex many-to-many query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, many-to-many

I've got 3 models: User, Team, and Membership -

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, :through => :memberships, :source => :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :teams, :through => :memberships

  def team_mates
    teams = Team.where(:members => id)
    team_mates = teams.members
  end
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team

  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :team_id, :presence => true
end
```

And, I can't quite figure out how to write the team_mates method in the User model. It should return an array of the other users that are in a team with the current_user. My thought is that I should be useing a scope to limit Team to only include teams where the current user is a member but I can't quite figure out the syntax. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the membership table to find users who share any team with the user you are calling the method on. Then to filter out duplicate users who share more than 1 team with current user, use distinct.

I haven't tested the below code, but hopefully it will get you on the right path:

```
def team_mates
  m = Membership.scoped.table
  Users.join(m).where(m[:team_id].in(team_ids)).project('distinct users.*')
end
```

**UPDATE**

Looks like some of the Arel methods in that answer don't have an easy mapping back to ActiveRecord land. (If someone knows how, I'd love to know!) And also it returns the 'current user'. Try this instead:

```
def team_mates
  User.joins(:memberships).where('memberships.team_id' => team_ids).where(['users.id != ?', self.id]).select('distinct users.*')
end
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like we're getting close to the solution. I had to cast User as a socoped.table too in order to get the join to work. But, now the function is returning an Arel::SelectManager instead of an array of Users. Any idea how to extract a user array from Arel::SelectManager? Here's my code (sorry for the awful formatting):
  `def team_mates
    m = Membership.scoped.table
    u = User.scoped.table
    u.join(m).where(m[:team_id].in(team_ids)).project('distinct users.*')
  end`

Comment: I'm googling around for how to convert that back to an ActiveRecord Relation object, which is what you would want. You can probably take the result of that last statement and do `.to_sql` then pass it to `User.find_by_sql`: `def team_mates; m = Membership.scoped.table; u = User.scoped.table; sql = u.join(m).where(m[:team_id].in(team_ids)).project('distinct users.*').to_sql; User.find_by_sql(sql); end`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. This is awesome and you've saved me so much time that I now get to read a bunch of stuff on Arel :) I'm in nerd heaven.

Answer (score 4):

How about?

```
User.joins(:memberships).joins(:teams).where("teams.id" => id).uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
scope team_mates, lambda {|user_id, teams| joins(:memberships).where(:team_id => teams, :user_id => user_id)}

def team_mates
  User.team_mates(self.id, self.teams.collect {|t| t.id})
end
```

Here is more info:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html